# this.model.toJSON() is not returning the items where the collection is, why?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, mustache, underscore.js

I have:

```
NotificationModel = App.BB.Model.extend({
    defaults : {
        read : false
    },
    urlRoot : '/notifications'
});


NotificationCollection = App.BB.Collection.extend({
    model: NotificationModel,
    url: '/notifications',
    initialize : function() {
        this.fetch();
    },
});

NotificationView = App.BB.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    render : function() {
       console.log((this.model.toJSON())
    }
});
```

This log is not returning the items fetched from the server. But when I do me.collection.length I do get the correct length. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Over nine million duplicates on how AJAX is not synchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments others have made are making reference to the `fetch` method being asynchronous.  So `this.fetch()` returns immediately.  If you are rendering your view immediately after this.fetch, the collection will still be empty.

You should put something like this in the view that renders your collection:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.collection.bind("reset", this.render);
}
```